# Which on turns the receiver on and which one turns the receiver off

Tags: c, gcc, serial-port, rs485

I am currently programming a half duplex serial port (RS485) in C (only one signal can be sent over the line at a time) and am trying to figure out how to turn the receiver off on the device when I send a request to the device on the serial port. I found the following code but am however not sure which one turns the receiver off and which one turns the receiver on

```
struct termios options;

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    if(on)
        options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    else
        options.c_cflag &= ~CREAD;
```

Can anyone help me decipher which one turns the receiver on and which one turns the receiver off?

Comment: Does the receiver have to be turned off?  Many of the RS485 receivers that I have used in the past handle this internally.

Comment: Yes it does, I keep getting the same message back I sent and thus a CRC error. Scope shows message being sent as well.